# How do I pass script name to layout from separate haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, haml

This is what I'm currently using:

```
haml :login_signup, :layout => :'main'
```

From the login_signup haml file, I would like to pass the name of the JS file to be parsed inside the :main haml file.

Reason? layout main.haml contains jquery reference. Rest of the haml files use different JS scripts that require jquery to be sourced first.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like `content_for`.

Here is how this works add something like this to your main ([source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method)):

```
= yield(:somejs)
```

And then fill it from the login_signup view:

```
- content_for(:somejs) do
  = javascript_include_tag :foo
```

Since you tagged also Sinatra there is a plugin for that functionality: https://github.com/foca/sinatra-content-for

Comment: =yield(:somejs) didnt work, but = yield_content :somejs kind of works. Same for the content_for (changed to content_for :somejs do).  But now it renders: [#<Proc:0x007f8ce7b3dff0@ .... haml location